# hdiutil convert not working and not telling me why

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, mount, file-conversion

I've been trying to create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive following instructions from multiple sites. I need to convert the .iso file to an .img using hdiutil. For starters, the syntax of the command is very unclear. The ubuntu site and the -help option of hdiutil say `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso` but the `man hdiutil` says `hdiutil convert ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img`. I have tried both ways and neither has worked. I don't get any sort of error message, and I know my paths are correct (when I try with an incorrect path it says so). The only thing printed in the terminal is

```
Usage:  hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
    hdiutil convert -help
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Either format should work, so I suspect there's something else wrong. Are there any spaces in the filenames? Is it possible you're using some fancy (and shell-incompatible) unicode characters (fancy dashes, nonbreaking spaces, something like that)?

Answer (score -1):

Use ETCG drivemaker file, much easier.

Heres the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y&t=421s

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you provided will answer the question.  Link-only answers are not the best way to help the OP and others.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review